# "DateParseError: Unknown datetime string format, unable to parse: ..." using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have some problems with my code in Python, Here are the test codes:

```
import pandas as pd

dict={'Country':['USA','China','Canada'],'Capitol':['Washington DC','Beijing','Ottawa'],'2015-01':[10,20,30],'2015-02':[15,25,35],'2015-03':[20,30,40],'2015-04':[10,20,30],'2015-05':[40,50,60],'2015-06':[20,30,40]}

sample = pd.DataFrame(dict)
sample.set_index(['Country','Capitol'],inplace=True)
```

Now, perform the groupby operation:

```
samplegrouped=sample.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(sample.columns,freq='Q'),axis=1).mean()
samplegrouped['ratio'] = samplegrouped['2015Q1']/samplegrouped['2015Q2']
```

I got this error:

```
DateParseError: Unknown datetime string format, unable to parse: ratio
```

If I just run

```
samplegrouped['2015Q1']/samplegrouped['2015Q2']
```

I got the right results. What is the problem and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have to do with the fact that you group on a `PeriodIndex`. This means, further columns to be added must have a name that is a valid date format. This error is indicative of that:

```
DateParseError: Unknown datetime string format, unable to parse: ratio
```

Since `'ratio'` is not a valid datetime format, the error is thrown.

So, once you finish grouping, convert the columns to string, if you don't really care about maintaining the `PeriodIndex` -

```
samplegrouped.columns = samplegrouped.columns.values.astype(str)
```

Now, your operation should work without any trouble -

```
samplegrouped['ratio'] = samplegrouped['2015Q1'] / samplegrouped['2015Q2']    
samplegrouped

                       2015Q1     2015Q2     ratio
Country Capitol                                   
USA     Washington DC    15.0  23.333333  0.642857
China   Beijing          25.0  33.333333  0.750000
Canada  Ottawa           35.0  43.333333  0.807692
```

Comment: Thanks!  That's exactly what I needed.